# Table Pagination Incorrect and Not limiting records - Bootstrap Datatable

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I have a bootstrap table that pulls json from another site and for some reason the pagination is incorrect:

http://fragrate.net/index.php?queryp=&task=searchplayers

If you see the bottom table:
Data Loads correctly
Clicking the records limit drop down doesn't limit records
Clicking Page 2 Refreshes the table but the data doesn't change

Here's where I got the table from:

http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/examples.html#pagination-table

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery DataTables, `datatables` tag is misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **CAUSE**

You have enabled [server-side pagination](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/examples.html#pagination-table) with `data-side-pagination="server"` attribute for `table` element.

> **SOLUTION #1**

Disable server-side pagination by removing `data-side-pagination="server"` attribute.

- Remove `data-side-pagination="server"` attribute
- Change response format so that it only contains array of objects. According to the [documentation](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/):

  > Note that the required server response format is different depending on whether the `sidePagination` option is specified. See the following examples:
  >
  > - [Without server-side pagination](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table-examples/blob/master/json/data1.json)
  > - [With server-side pagination](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table-examples/blob/master/json/data2.json)

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sxqhmpch/) for code and demonstration.

> **SOLUTION #2**

Implement pagination on the server. Among other parameters browser sends `limit` parameter containing number of records requested and `offset` parameter containing starting record.

Comment: When I remove this attribute that table becomes blank. (Empty). :(

Comment: Cool, didn't know it also passed the limit and offset variables. Nice.